# Azure SQL Server Sync Data between different Accounts

Tags: sql-server, azure, data-synchronization, azure-data-sync

We have two separate Azure Accounts. We wish to one way sync SQL database table data every x minutes between the two.

Account 1 => Sql Database => Table 
Account 2 => Sql database => Table

SQL Server Sync group can not be used as these are two separate accounts. Is there an app or service which can be used ? We are open to all solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is actually fairly easy to do yourself.  What I would do is use a combinations of [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) and Azure SQL Integrated Change Tracking.  Integrated Change Tracking gives you a way to ask the Azure SQL Database to tell you which rows have been inserted, updated or deleted.  From this you can query these rows to then have them be sent to the other database.  Using Azure Functions you can create the code to get these changes and then send them for you.  The added ability of Azure Functions to do scheduling is also really helpful here.

Since you specifically asked about solutions that do this, I will mention the service I work on called [Cotega](http://cotega.com/datasync) and I am happy to help you do this, but once again with your requirements you might find it fairly easy to build yourself.